# Add source folder to the python interpreter of jupyter notebooks or jupyter lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am including some notebooks in my library to work as documentation.

I would like to run the jupyter notebook command or jupyter lab including the libray src folder. That way I don't have to compile and reinstall my library for the documentation every time I make a modification (although the kernel needs to be restarted).

Is there a way to add this folder to the python interpreter in the jupyter kernel outside the notebook cells?

Thanks for any advice.